# Logstash grok filtered data as NUMBER, but why the filtered data in Kibana still dislay as String

Tags: elastic-stack

As an elk newbie, I used grok filter in Logstash to filter a number data as a field as such: `%{NUMBER:duration}`. But when I browse the filtered data with Kibana, I saw from its settings tab that the field - duration - is still with a Sting data type.

I indeed need this field as a Number data type also in Kibana web console, so that I can use it in the visualization. Anyone has any idea about how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the fields going from Logstash to Elasticsearch are stored as String. If you want to change the data-type you need to explicitly mention it in the Logstash Configuration file.

Assuming your field name is duration, in your Logstash config file within filter use mutate filter to convert the field from String to Integer. It is shown as below:-

```
mutate {
convert => { "duration" => "integer" }
       }
```

It will now store duration field as Integer in Elasticsearch and you can visualize it in Kibana as an Integer field.

Comment: Great hint I got from u! Thanks so much, but plz refer to this link, after your hint I found it. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-convert From this link, the format is way different from your answer, say in the logstash site they define mutate convert type as hash other than array, whereas you gave an array type. So please modify it, then I check this as the right answer :)

Comment: Hi
I have tried using the above syntax and it is converting. Though I agree it is a hashtype but it's accepting an array as well in this case.
Can you try using the above mentioned syntax if it works in your case?

Comment: great! I approved it :)